# Interleaved sort keys in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Have a few questions related to the interleaved key.

1. Is the order in which we specify the columns of interleaved sort keys important? I understand that Redshift gives equal importance to each key mentioned in the interleaved keys but does the order in which they are specified matter?
2. I also see that the **sortkeys** are given numbers (and also *negative numbers*) like below. *what do the negative numbers indicate below?*

[image]

3. does the query performance get affected if there are around 8 keys configured as interleaved sort keys compared to if there were 4, does Redshift have to scan lesser blocks because of the number of columns configured as the interleaved sort keys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you my quick answers to these questions but first let's understand what is trying to be achieved with sort keys.  While many benefits can be achieved with sort keys (like merge joins) there is one dominating benefit that will make the biggest change (for large tables) and that is table scan optimization.  If the table metadata indicates that the block is not needed for the query then this block will not be scanned (read) from disk.  If a large percentage of the blocks can be eliminated from the scan the query may be significantly sped up.

This can only happen if the table metadata is valid for the blocks in question AND if the metadata shows that the data is not needed.  A WHERE clause needs to be included in the query and the comparison has to be against the raw column value and a literal (like WHERE A = 1).  To provide any benefit there needs to be blocks for column A where the metadata indicates that A does not the value 1 for this block.  To provide significant value the metadata for all the blocks of column A need to have a fair percentage of these to not possibly contain the value 1.

The sorting of the table by its sortkeys will determine which rows are in which blocks and therefore what max and min values for the block will be represented in the blocks metadata.  If A has values 1 through 10 and A is the only sort key then the first blocks for column A will have 1, then set set 2, and so on.  Assuming that the table has enough rows to fill up many more than 10 blocks (per slice) then the WHERE A = 1 clause can prevent the scanning of most of the table's data from disk.  A big performance win.

The complexity comes in when you have multiple sort keys (interleaved or not).  If you sort by A and then by B (also having the values 1 through 10) you may or may not get good "block rejection" on a query with the where clause "WHERE B = 1".  This will depend on how many rows are in your table and how big your cluster is (number of slices) (as well as the table distribution but let's not get overly complicated as this is complex enough).  If you have enough rows with A = 1 that the rows with B = 1 can fill up many blocks of data then there can still be good "block rejection".  However, the size of the table needs to be much much larger than in the A = 1 where clause to achieve the performance boost.  Similarly a 3rd sort key will need an even greater size of table (as compared to the number of slices in the cluster) to achieve the same benefit.

Whether the sort key are compound or interleaved doesn't matter a whole lot in this analysis.  Interleaved sort keys have a window of table size where they will out perform compound.  Also this benefit is only worth the time of selecting on A and B independently are of equal importance to you.

#1: So to answer your first question the number of sort keys definitely matters.  The more sort keys you have the harder it is to gain any benefit from "block rejection".  This is true for compound keys and especially for interleaved keys.  Here's why - if I have 5 compound sort keys I may only get "block rejection" benefit from the first 2 and the others don't hurt me by screwing up the sorting of the higher keys.  However for interleaved all keys are treated with equal importance so by adding the 4th and 5th key to the list I've significantly hurt the "block rejection" benefit of the first 3 keys.  Bottom line - number of interleaved keys matters but the order doesn't (at least not much).  With 7 interleaved keys you are very likely getting near zero value.

#2: The negative values on the "odd" sort keys just indicates that these keys are part of an interleaved sort key list.  If the keys were compound then they would all be positive numbers.  It is just a flag.

#3: I've already hit on this but yes, 8 keys will likely give no benefit at all.  I highly recommend that you don't use interleaved sort keys as they cause more performance issue than they solve.  The tag line sounds good - "equal weight to all sort keys" - but the reality is that for most people the value they are getting from each interleaved sort key is equal - zero.

I've worked on Redshift for many years and with many clients, I've never gotten more than 3 sort keys to truly matter in the performance of queries.  Doing this took a lot of analysis and that was for just 3 keys.  These were compound keys in then end as there was some value to prioritizing one of the sort keys over the others.  Interleaved would have given these keys a balanced but poor boost in performance but the better solution was compound.

The other benefit with compound sort keys is that if you try to get performance from 3 keys but miss you are still likely getting benefit from 2. With interleaved you will likely get benefit from none.  Also, you can have more (later) compound sort keys that can provide benefit to a common downstream ORDER BY clause AND NOT mess up the scan benefit of the other sort keys.

I cannot stress this enough - don't use interleaved sort keys on Redshift unless you know what you are doing and have done the supporting performance analysis.

I do this analysis for clients and it is involved.  Even optimizing for a couple of compound sort keys can get tricky.  Most are far better off making a quick assessment of their most common WHERE clause values, putting the top one first in a compound sort key list, the second one second, and then add whatever other columns seem important to the end of the list.  You can do the analysis in 20 minutes and will get the majority of the possible benefit.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am building a Tableau dashboard using Redshift with few filters using interleaved sort key and i do see that the performance is better compared to using compound sort keys. My fact table has 2 million rows and dimension table has around 800 million rows. The filters in Tableau dashboard can be applied in any order so i am using interleaved keys, but not sure if i should use all column present in filter as interleaved keys or only subset of them and how can i optimise / analyse interleaved keys performance

Comment: It sounds like you have some columns used a filters but you don't know which ones will be used in any query, right?  With compound keys you can tune for one or two of the possibilities but not all so on aggregate the performance is worse.  Does this sound right?  If not then I expect that tuning of the compound keys wasn't successful.  To figure this out you will need to evaluate queries with different WHERE clause columns.  The query report for each will tell you if the query ran with a "range-restricted" scan which indicates that the metadata was used to aid performance.

Comment: Then look at the number of rows scanned as compared to the total rows in the table, this will let you know how effective the "block rejecting"/"range-restricting" scan was. Do this for the difference WHERE clauses and you can get a sense of how effect each is being in your cases. To dig deeper you will need to analyze the minvalue and maxvalue in stv_blocklist which lets you look at what the metadata says about the block. This can be tricky but does allow you to see how different sort keys (and modes) impact the metadata and thus the query performance. This can be done for either sort key type

Comment: Rereading your comment - did you mean 2 billion rows in the fact table?  That's how I took it.  There is another factor that could be in play - the metadata filtering happens pre-join so if your WHERE clause is on a dim-table column it is likely not being used for metadata filtering on the fact-table (it is possible based on join type and if the column is in the ON clause with equality comparison).  The join could add a layer of complexity.  In general you want the fastest response for dashboards so joining is often too heavy.